# Group Contours on lines using OpenCv and Python

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I have the given Image and I need to group the contours found in groups.

[image]

For example, I need to know what which elements are aligned with F1 and F2.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do it?

I have managed to find the contours of the image and know their X and Y points, but I don't know how to effectively compare these points and find the groups of contours that belong to the same line.

Comment: can you please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an algorithm that merges lines with similar angles and certain distance between into a new line. I used it to detect borders of a piece of paper I wanted to cut out of the picture. There were many lines on the same border returned by `HoughLines` that I wanted to combine into one long line. Take a look at my [repository](https://github.com/AndrejHafner/ScanIt/blob/master/image_processing/image_processing/image_processing.cpp) and look for `mergeLines` function.